# How to notify all organization users using Signalr?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I am trying to implement Signalr notification system with organization specific.

**Database Structure :**

```
Organization:
   Id[uniqueidentifier]
   Name[nvarchar(max)]

AspNetUsers:
   Id[nvarchar(128)]
   UserName[nvarchar]
   Email(nvarchar)

User.Organization:
   Id[uniqueidentifier]
   UserId[nvarchar(128)]
   OrganizationId[uniqueidentifier]
```

*So , one user can have multiple organizations and one organization can have multiple users.*

### I want to build a notification system to inform all users in an organization if new user is registered on the same organization.

**Register User Method :**

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

**Create Organization Method :**

```
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name")] Organization organization)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            organization.Id = Guid.NewGuid();

            organization.User_Organization.Add(new User_Organization() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(),UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId(),OrganizationId = organization.Id});

            db.Organizations.Add(organization);

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(organization);
    }
```

**Add More Users to a organization :**

```
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,UserId,OrganizationId")] User_Organization user_Organization)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            user_Organization.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            db.User_Organization.Add(user_Organization);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.AspNetUsers, "Id", "Email", user_Organization.UserId);
        ViewBag.OrganizationId = new SelectList(db.Organizations, "Id", "Name", user_Organization.OrganizationId);
        return View(user_Organization);
    }
```

**My Hub Class :**

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void Announce_serverSide_function(string message)
    {
        Clients.All.Announce_clientSide_function(message);
    }

    public Task JoinRoom(string roomName)
    {
        return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, roomName);
    }

    public Task LeaveRoom(string roomName)
    {
        return Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, roomName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call **some** dynamic method (you need to implement that method on client side) on specific group.

```
public void JoinRoom(string roomName)
{
    Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, roomName).Wait();
    string playerName = // get player name somehow
    Clients.Group(roomName).NotifyUserAdded(playerName);
}
```

**Client code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function()){
    var hub = $.connection.myHub;
    hub.client.notifyPlayerAdded = function(playerName)
    {
         // show message about player entered room
    }
}
```

it's also important to be careful about casing of method names.